# Inverse of the restriction of a matrix identified as an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $H$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space and let $T$ be a bijective linear map on $H$. Let $\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^k H_k$ be any orthogonal decomposition of $H$. Consider the restriction map

$$T_p:=T|_{({\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^p H_k})^\perp}\qquad 1\leq p \leq k.$$

obviously, $T_p$ is bijective. Now, I am confused about the fact that

$T_p$ has also a matrix representation and the matrix may not be a square one. Then we cannot explicitly find $T_p^{-1}$. However,bijectivity of $T_p$ ensures existence of such inverse. What is wrong with this.

Please help me on this, a detailed answer (example) will be of very much help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $T_p$ is bijective, at least unless you also restrict its codomain.  If you have a bijection $f:A\to B$ between two sets and then restrict it to a subset $C\subset A$, the restricted map $f|_C:C\to B$ is not a bijection anymore.  It's still injective, but it won't be surjective anymore since some elements of $B$ were hit by elements of $A\setminus C$, not by elements of $C$.  If you additionally change the codomain to the image $f(C)$, then the map $C\to f(C)$ that you get will be bijective.

Comment: Definitely agreed with your comment@EricWofsey. However, if I consider the map $T_p$ by restricting its codomain, then I will have a Bijective map. Now, what is its inverse? What is its matrix representation?

Comment: Well to get a matrix representation you need to pick a basis for the domain and codomain first, and there won't be any canonical choice for those bases.